# Lucene Luke. How much is the Last search time?

Tags: lucene, luke

Luke displays results like this:

Last search time: 67999 us

What is 'us'? How to convert that to ms?

Comment: I would never display results like that...

Comment: I’m not sure if @Luke knows the First thing about search, be he sure knows the Last!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This actually means μs, or microseconds (which, unfortunately, isn't ASCII, so the Greek letter mu is replaced by a similar-looking u). To get ms, divide by 1000.